# Combine objects into new object as json for post for web api request

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rest, typescript

I am using Angular 4 with Typescript and ASP Core with C#. I am trying to combine objects together before calling a post to my web api.  Currently I have two objects with values that I want to post as one object.

Let say I have two interfaces

```
export interface Student {
    name: string;
}

export interface Teacher {
    name: string;
}
```

And I wanted my json in my body of the post to look like this as my ASP Core is expecting this as a parameter to the web api request.

```
{
    "StudentName": "John Doe",
    "TeacherName": "Jane Doe"
}
```

I am using the following to create the json for the body but this puts it into two separate records in the json.  This also does not allow me to select specific properties if my interfaces had more than what the request required.

```
const body = JSON.stringify({ student, teacher });
```

Next I tried to access only the specific member variables in the JSON.stringify method, but for some reason it does not work.  In addition, if this even worked it would end up with two properties with the same name.

```
const body = JSON.stringify({ student.name, teacher.name });
```

I am not sure if this is a typescript, javascript or angular issue.  I tried searching online for some help but I don't think I am using the right keywords.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're not labeling your object items:

```
const body = JSON.stringify({ StudentName: student.name, TeacherName: teacher.name })
```

is the expected format.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple I was missing, thank you.  I will mark as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.